# Animating CandleStick Chart from Data Stored in ArrayList

Tags: java, animation, javafx, charts, candlestick-chart

I have one second candlestick data stored in an ArrayList of 'BarData' objects which contain open, high, low and close data as well as the timestamp. I am aggregating this data into 5 minute bars and displaying the data on a customized JavaFX XYChart to generate candles.

The aggregation code works fine and I can display the 5 minute bars created from 1 second bars.

Now I want to animate the creation of the 5 minute chart using the 24,300 sets of 1 second data I have in the list so I can replay the data as if it were a live market datafeed.

I have tried to use Timeline but am struggling. Do I need to create one KeyFrame for every update of the series data?

Here is the working loop that aggregates the 1 second data in 'sublist' into a 5 minute chart. Can anyone advise how I might go about animating this?

```
        for (BarData bar : sublist) 
        {
           String label = "";
           if ((bar.getDateTime().getMinute()%5 == 0) && bar.getDateTime().getSecond() == 0)
           {
              label = dtf.format(bar.getDateTime());
              series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(label, bar.getOpen(), bar));
           }
           else
           {
              // Just updating values so no need to update label.
              int idxOfLastBarInList = series.getData().size()-1;
              XYChart.Data<String, Number> data = series.getData().get(idxOfLastBarInList);
              BarData prevBar = (BarData)(data.getExtraValue());
              prevBar.update(bar); // Modifies bar based on new bar data.
              data.setExtraValue(prevBar);
              series.getData().set(idxOfLastBarInList, data);
           }
        }
```

The chart ends up looking like this:

[Sample Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzYp1.png)

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to start at second 0 and animate the chart (increasing the amount of data displayed)?

Comment: Correct. Each 5 minute bar will contain 300 one second data records. I would like the bars to update as if the data were coming in realtime from a stock quote datafeed.

I did think of an alternative way of doing this without animation, which was to start a separate thread that feeds the data to a Quote Listener in the chart application and have the chart update second by second. 

I thought the animation feature might be simpler to do but it seems after some effort that it might not be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, I realised that the line:

```
series.getData().set(idxOfLastBarInList, data);
```

does not work to force the chart to redraw the bar. In order to get the bar to update immediately, I had to remove the bar and then re-add the bar. It seems a strange workaround but it does work. If anyone has a better answer I would be glad to hear it.

```
series.getData().remove(idxOfLastBarInList);
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(label, prevBar.getOpen(), prevBar));
```

Replacing the 'set' code with the 'remove' followed by 'add' ensured my candle was redrawn.